# Automatically inserting column names for table in TOAD for Oracle

Tags: oracle, user-interface, plsql, toad

I am looking for a way to automatically insert column names in TOAD for Oracle to make it easier for writing queries.

Ideally, I would like to type something like the following:

```
select * from myTable;
```

Then, when I right-click on `*`, I would have the option to insert all known column names for that table.

Is it possible in Toad?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> on that the selected table name, and in the schema browser, select the `Columns` tab, then select all columns. Then drag the selection, *do not copy&paste*,  **back** into the editor, and you have your comma separated column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column_name || ','
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
and owner = 'SOME_OWNER'
order by column_id;
```

The right click on output of field names in data grid and select Export Data (to clipboard as tab delimited, don't include quoting or column headers).

Now copy/paste where u need it.  Nice thing is that you can:

1. Use this SQL in any IDE, not just Toad
2. Modify output if needed, as I do in triggers to add ':old' or ':new' prefixes to each field for example, or change order.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to generate the statement from the schema browser-> columns tab

Select the columns you want, then right click and select the 'generate statement' menu item,then select the command you want to generate (Select/Insert/Delete).

The script then gets copied to clipboard, for you to paste at your leisure.